Sportsbook Middleware for Syncing User Data
Dylan here, I've been working on a startup for the past year now, AI sports predictions with real AI (not chatGPT or simple Linear Regression models) and As I am nearing launch I am needing a solution to connect to user's sportsbooks to pull their data into my app in order to offer incentives, track their bets, and show the ROI of my tool over time. With that being said I have a theoretical system to achieve this and I need some input from the stackoverflow community to validate my idea for this system and get some feedback.
The System Flow (think of the fintech "Plaid" but for sportsbooks):
User signs up for my app -> User is shown a list of sportsbooks -> User selects their sportsbook -> user signs into their sportsbook from my site, which sends the credentials to my application -> my backend sends an auth request to the sportsbook with the user's credentials -> if successful sportsbook returns a cookie, JWT token, or an Access token I can use to successfully authenticate request to the sportsbook on the user's behalf to query the data.
Now with this in mind, what is wrong with this system, what can be improved, and would this be efficient at scale ex. 100k users.
